# How to find GoogleAnalytics ${YOUR_TRACKING_ID} in 2020?

Tags: google-analytics-sdk

When I want to use GoogleAnalytics in app, I read the doc in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4
, but I can not find the ${YOUR_TRACKING_ID}, the detail as following:

Create the file app/src/res/xml/global_tracker.xml with the following content:
Replace ${YOUR_TRACKING_ID} with your tracking ID.enter code here

Where can I find my tracking ID?the website cannot find this id in 2020.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? Asking for a friend :)

Answer (score 0):

**[Solution : Solved]**
Use your google analytics project ID.

1. Go to the Google Analytics
2. Select the Google Analytics Account
3. Select the Properties & Apps
4. Select your App

You can see the ID there. It's something can see below the project name